# How to use Format File (.fmt) in PowerShell SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: sql, powershell, format, bulkinsert

Is it possible to use Format File (.fmt) in PowerShell SqlBulkCopy?

I have a script in PowerShell that use the Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy but I can not found how to use Format Files with this method...

What I'm using:

```
$bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy("connection string",
 [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock) 
$bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "table name"
$bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0 
$bulkcopy.batchsize = 50000
```

I'm using a Stream Reader to read the file to import:

```
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("txt file", "encoding")
```

I can set delimiters in the Stream Reader:

```
$columns = (Get-Content "txt file" -First 1).Split("delimiter")
```

and define if the First Row is the header:

```
if ($isFirstRowHeader -eq $true) { 
$null = $reader.readLine()
}
```

But I can see an option to use the FORMATFILE (.fmt) like in SQL Server:

```
BULK INSERT myTestFormatFiles   
   FROM 'C:\myTestFormatFiles-c.Dat'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\myTestFormatFiles.Fmt');
```

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` does not use the `BULK INSERT` statement and it has no support for format files. Format files are fairly simple to parse, but it would be even simpler to invoke `bcp` from PowerShell (after all, `bcp` is the one generating such files in the first place).

Comment: Thank you for your response @JeroenMostert! My objective is to use only one thing and I like the way of SqlBulkCopy works but if it's not possible to use format files I will then try use the bcp from PowerShell.